# Connection pooling with Redisson

Tags: java, redis, amazon-elasticache, redisson

My application makes a lot of calls to Redis, I dont want to create a client everytime. Is there a way I can create a connection pool and use connections from the pool whenever I need to connect to Redis. Please note that redis is in single server mode here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Redisson you don't need to create a connection pool because Redisson already maintains it for you. Just create Redisson instance as singleton (it's fully threadsafe) and use it.

Comment: I have redis configured in master-slave mode. I am connecting to redis via Redisson using yaml configuration file. But I want to get information about Redis like how much memory it has, no of clients etc. How can I do that with Redisson. I guess we can get it via RedisConnection. But how to get single RedisConnection from pool of connections or from RedissonClient?

Comment: Could you open an issue regarding your feature request? As workaround you could use low-level RedisClient object. https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/10.-additional-features#107-low-level-redis-client

Comment: Please have a look - https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2439

Comment: Just a quick question - when using redisson-spring-boot-starter, can we use autowiring to get hold of RedisClient/RedisConnection? or we need to again configure RedisClient via RedisClientConfig from scratch. I don't want to duplicate the connection details in code and yaml file.

Comment: Yes you can, just define `spring.redis.redisson.config` property